# Specify Path for Installing ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have two versions of Ruby installed.
How can I install my ruby gem so that it gets installed in the version specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you need to specify which Ruby you're using first, then call the appropriate `gem` command once that's set.

RVM, `rbenv` and others all work in different ways. For example, with RVM:

```
rvm use 2.4.1
gem install xyz -v 1.2.3
```

For `rbenv` it's a bit different:

```
rbenv local 2.4.1
gem install xyz -v 1.2.3
```

Where that generates a `.ruby-version` file in your current directory.

Since the `gem` command itself is Ruby, the proper Ruby environment must be set, which is where the multi-Ruby version managers come in.